# cant send key stroke only to Word Through my program that use KeyboardHook

Tags: c#, winforms

i have my program that Captures weighing and send it to a open window.

its work excellent , except with a single software - **Microsoft Word**

I have tried everything and have no idea why.

my code:

this is the GlobalKeyBoardHook.cs class

```
public class GlobalKeyboardHook
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LLKeyboardHook callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint theardID);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    public delegate int LLKeyboardHook(int Code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam);

    public struct keyBoardHookStruct
    {
        public int vkCode;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }

    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
    const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;

    LLKeyboardHook llkh;
    public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();

    IntPtr Hook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

    // This is the Constructor. This is the code that runs every time you create a new GlobalKeyboardHook object
    public GlobalKeyboardHook()
    {
        llkh = new LLKeyboardHook(HookProc);
        // This starts the hook. You can leave this as comment and you have to start it manually (the thing I do in the tutorial, with the button)
        // Or delete the comment mark and your hook will start automatically when your program starts (because a new GlobalKeyboardHook object is created)
        // That's why there are duplicates, because you start it twice! I'm sorry, I haven't noticed this...
        // hook(); <-- Choose!
    }
    ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
    { unhook(); }

    public void hook()
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, llkh, hInstance, 0);
    }

    public void unhook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook);
    }

    public int HookProc(int Code, int wParam, ref keyBoardHookStruct lParam)
    {
        if (Code >= 0)
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
            if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                KeyEventArgs kArg = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                    KeyDown(this, kArg);
                else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                    KeyUp(this, kArg);
                if (kArg.Handled)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(Hook, Code, wParam, ref lParam);
    }
```

// --- from here start the program --

```
GlobalKeyboardHook gHook;
gHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(); // Create a new GlobalKeyboardHook
gHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gHook_KeyDown);
foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
{
     gHook.HookedKeys.Add(key);
}
gHook.hook();
 public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == KeyPressg)  //Pause-Break //19
            {
                ProccName = (GetActiveWindowTitle().ToString());
                Start(ProccName);
                gHook.unhook();
                gHook.hook();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
  private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                return Buff.ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]   
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public void Start(string NAME)
        {

             MSG = lblMSG.Text.Trim();
            IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
            for (int i = 0; (i < 60) && (zero == IntPtr.Zero); i++) 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                zero = FindWindow(null, NAME);
            }
            if (zero != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                try
                {
                    string text = lblMSG.Text.Trim();
                    text = text.Replace("gHook", "");

                    //OLD
                    //foreach (char c in text)
                    //    SendKeys.SendWait(c.ToString());

                    //NEW
                    if (text.Length == 0) return;
                    SendKeys.SendWait(text);

                    if (MyParam._KeyAfter == "Enter")
                    {
                        MyParam.FromKEY = true;
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                    }
                    else if (MyParam._KeyAfter == "TAB")
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                    }
                    else if (MyParam._KeyAfter == "Key Down")
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                    }

                    SendKeys.Flush();

                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why ?

thanks

EDIT

i fount the problem place:

```
 public void Start(string NAME)
    {
        // --> NAME  Contain -->    Word‪ - 123.docx  for example when Word window open

        MSG = lblMSG.Text.Trim();
        IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
        for (int i = 0; (i < 60) && (zero == IntPtr.Zero); i++) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            zero = FindWindow(null, NAME);  // <-- in Word zero Always Contain 0  And never goes on in the code so stuck
        }
        // <--- the program stops here and stuck 
        if (zero != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
```

Comment: Does it work if you run your program as an administrator? If MS word is running as an admin and your program isn't, your program won't be able to intercept key presses... maybe? Seems unlikely, hopefully this helps.

Comment: i try to run as administrator, and same problem....

Comment: i have same problem, Did someone mess with that ? How is it possible to check the name of the window that opens really true?

Comment: i update my question